# Java audio: How to continuously write bytes to an audio file as they are being generated?

Tags: java, audio

I am currently successfully sending buffers of bytes to a `SourceDataLine` in a loop as they are generated:

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2;

AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, true);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
line.open(format, 4410);
line.start();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(line.getBufferSize());

while (true) {
  buffer.clear();
  int available = line.available() / SAMPLE_SIZE;
  for (int i = 0; i < available; i++) {
    // generate some bytes ....
    buffer.putShort(....);
  }

  line.write(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.position());
}
```

This makes the samples I'm generating audible, awesome. Now I want to save these same samples to an audio file as they are being generated, as well as hearing them. It is open-ended, I want to be able to stop the program at any time and the audio file will contain all samples generated up to that point.

I did some searching and found you can create an `AudioInputStream` from a buffer of bytes and then use that `AudioInputStream` to write to an audio file using the `AudioSystem.write()` function:

```java
File wavFile = new File("path/to/wav/file.wav");
AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array()),
  audioFormat,
  buffer.position());

AudioSystem.write(stream, fileType, wavFile);
```

But this only creates a file with a single cycle of samples. How do I write out the samples continuously to an audio file as I am generating them, in the same way I am able to hear the samples being continuously generated through the `SourceDataLine`?

Any insight appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just keep the stream open until you've finished?

Comment: Right, but how do I add new bytes to the stream? It seems to only be able to construct the `AudioInputStream` with a `ByteArrayInputStream` that already has the bytes defined.... how do I "stream" new bytes as they become available?

Comment: Maybe this can't be done with WAV (which requires knowing the number of bytes beforehand) but can with some other audio format?

Comment: I must be missing something. I don't see why you can't create the stream, write to it as you receive and finally close it ...

Comment: I don't see a way to write new bytes to a `ByteArrayInputStream`? Or an `AudioInputStream`? Maybe if it was an output stream.... but it looks like the `AudioSystem` requires an input stream because it reads from it to write the output.

Comment: I get it now, sorry ;) I see the problem - the writing is not happening to a stream as such but directly into the mixer. I'm not sure, but it's possible that some other API *would* allow writing to a stream

Answer (score 0):

A few thought about handling "endless" data and need-to-know-beforehand headers.

1. Don't trip over by using `ByteBuffer` against its defined semantic.

```java
// wrong or - at least - counter-intuitive
buffer.clear();
buffer.put...(...);
line.write(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.position());
```

It is meant to be used like this:

```java
buffer.rewind();
buffer.put...(...);
buffer.flip();
line.write(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.remaining());
```

... although in this specific case there is no real benefit. `ByteBuffer#flip` is very important for `ByteBuffer#get...` methods, for example if you use NIO for writing to a file.

2. Simply write to a file **without** a RIFF/WAV header. Depending on your requirements, you could just serialize* your `AudioFormat` and save it in a different place (out-of-band), preferably as file metadata (uncommon but most often possible). This is possible because there is no complex multiplexing needed in your case.

- or keep your AudioFormat hardcoded even at file playback's side - not recommended.

```java
try (var fileChannel = FileChannel.open(Path.of("test.pcm"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
```

```java
   buffer.flip();
   line.write(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.remaining());
   buffer.flip();
   fileChannel.write(buffer);
```

... or use a better suited container format.

```java
}
```

3. The same data you read from `line` can also be read from a file. It's the exact same bitstream - the joys of digital data.